# npm install frozen when mvnw exectued

Tags: npm, jhipster

[frozen command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZpBo.png)

I am trying to launch a jhipster application, and when I run mvnw in my project it dosen't execute and exits with status code 1.
this is my error message

Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (npm install) on project project: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details rather than adding lengthy comments. Did it happen also during project generation? Does it work when you run `npm install` directly? It could be a network issue, are you behind a corporate firewall? Have you tried to run in 2 processes `mvnw -P-webapp`and `npm start` as described in your project's README.md or in online doc https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#as-a-maven-project